# getting null value from sharedpreference after returning the right value at first

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i have made set and get method for shared preference in a service class. working well for first time , like it returns right value for the first time but after that it is returning null value.

my code:

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        context=getApplicationContext();


        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent("Notification"));
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    //sharedpreference
    public static void setDefaults(String key, String value, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.clear();

        editor.putString(key, value);

        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }

    public static void ClearAllPreferences(Context context){

        //remove all your prefs
        context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0).edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

i could not understand why the problem is occurring. i have tried a lot but found no solution. please help me on solve this

Comment: Your both sharedpreference are different. 1) When you store value 2) When you clear sp

Comment: how ? can you solve this please. ? but same code running well in another project well

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences prefs =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` and then `prefs.edit().clear().commit();` Also check your context must not be `null`

Comment: @AAA check above comment

Comment: Can you tell me where and how you have used this shared preferences?? Also tell us the flow of this service with respect to your `SharedPreferences` usage

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya same result not working

Comment: @JimitPatel i used from many activities . i declared service from login activity . where i set value after successfully logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Your coding skills not good try this code it will work fine.

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {

Context context;
static SharedPreferences prefs;
static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    context = getApplicationContext();
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent("Notification"));
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


//sharedpreference
public static void setDefaults(String key, String value, Context context) {
    editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();

}

public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {

    return prefs.getString(key, null);
}

public static void ClearAllPreferences(Context context) {

    //remove all your prefs
    prefs.edit().clear().commit();
}
```

}

Comment: score for coding skills not good. @AAA got lot in his pocket to learn... An opportunity to be precise